# correctly terminate akka actors in scala

Tags: scala, actor, akka

I've write sample code that starts an actor, kills it and finishes execution.

```
object PureAkka {
  def main(argv : Array[String]) = {
    val actorSystem : ActorSystem = ActorSystem("main")
    val actor : ActorRef = actorSystem.actorOf(Props( new Actor {
      override def receive = {
        case x => println(x)
      }
      override def preStart() = println("prestart")
      override def postStop() = println("poststop")
    } ) )
    Thread.sleep(15000)
    actor ! PoisonPill
  }
}
```

This code prints:

```
[info] prestart
[info] poststop
```

But it refuses to stop until I kill the process with Ctrl-C

What does application wait for? How can I stop it in a proper way?

Comment: The Akka documentation might help where it says `context.stop` at http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.0.3/#akka.actor.Actor .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps making a call to ActorSystem.shutdown() would do the trick.

According to the [akka docs](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.0.3/#akka.actor.ActorSystem):

> abstract def  **`shutdown(): Unit`**
>
> Stop this actor system. This will stop the guardian actor, which in turn will recursively stop all    its child actors, then the system guardian (below which the logging actors reside) and the execute all registered termination handlers (see ActorSystem.registerOnTermination).

Comment: Please note: [as of Akka 2.4](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/project/migration-guide-2.3.x-2.4.x.html#Actor_system_shutdown) you should use `ActorSystem.terminate()`. This returns a `Future[Terminated]` you could possibly wait for.